# Enviar Mensaje/archivo con micro python

Tags: python

Planteo la trama a ver si me podeís ayudar. Es la siguiente: 
Estoy unsando dos dispositivos que trabajan con lenguaje micro python y tienen chips para usar wifi según lo programes. Pues bien básicamente la idea es desarrollar un programa que en el chip servidor (de ahora en adelante chipS) Se activa el wifi en modo AP ( Access Point ) como servidor para que el chip cliente (de ahora en adelante chipC) se conecte a el y éste le envie un fichero.txt por medio de socket ya que realizar una coexion tipo FTP no hay libreria de ésta en micropython. Aunque es curioso porque desde Windows con el cliente Filezilla si que me puede conectar al chipS y subir un archivo.Que básicamente es lo que quiero hacer pero con el chipC.

En fin si alguien sabe usar una libreria FTP adaptada a micropython y me explica como se usa también lo acepto.

Pues bien de momento lo estoy intentando con socket pero no se que falla o como se haría, por ejemplos que he leido he realizado la siguiente programación pero me da errores igualmente.

En el caso de chipS el código usado es :

```
import socket                   # Import socket module
import network
import gc
from network import WLAN
from network import Server

def iniciarFTP():
    try:
        wlan = network.WLAN(mode=network.WLAN.STA)
        wlan.init(mode=WLAN.AP, ssid='Gateway1', auth=(WLAN.WPA2,'witeklab@2018'), channel=7, antenna=WLAN.INT_ANT)
        server = Server(login=('micro', 'python'), timeout=600)
        #server.timeout(300)
        #print(server.isrunning())
        print(wlan.ifconfig())
        return True
    except:
        return False

#Iniciamos servidor:
iniciarFTP()
host = ''
port = 60000                     # Reserve a port for your service.
s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
gc.collect()
s.bind((host, port))            # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                     # Now wait for client connection.

print ('Server listening....')

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print ('Got connection from', addr)
    data = conn.recv(256)
    print('Server received', repr(data))

    with open('received_file.txt', 'wb') as f:
        print ('file opened')
        while True:
            print('receiving data...')
            s.setblocking(True)
            print('Memoria->',str(gc.mem_free()))
            data = s.recv(256)
            print('M despues->',str(gc.mem_free()))
            print('data=%s', (data))
            if not data:
                break
            # write data to a file
            f.write(data)

        f.close()
        print('Successfully get the file')
        s.close()
        print('connection closed')

        conn.send('Thank you for connecting')
    conn.close()
    gc.collect()
```

Y al recibir la conexion del cliente indica 'Got connection from ('192.168.4.2',49429)
[image: ChipS , le llega la conexcion del cliente]
Pero en el cliente ya ha fallado:

Este es el código usado en el chipC:

```
from network import WLAN

import socket
import sys


def buscarWifi(ssid):
    #Ponemos el wifi en modo estacion:
    wlan = WLAN(mode=WLAN.STA)

    #Buscamos wifi:
    redes = wlan.scan()
    print('Redes disponibles: ',len(redes))
    #for c in range(len(redes)):
        #print(c,'->',redes[c])

        #if ssid in redes[c]: //Otra opción de encontrar el ssid
        #print("Encontrado en:",redes[c])
        #return True
    for red in redes:
        if red.ssid == ssid:
            wlan.connect(red.ssid, auth=(red.sec,'witeklab@2018'), timeout=5000)
            while not wlan.isconnected():
                machine.idle() # save power while waiting
            print('WLAN connection succeeded!')
            return True,wlan
            break
        else:
            return False,wlan
ok,w = buscarWifi('Gateway1')
if ok:
    ip = w.ifconfig()
    #(ip, subnet, gateway, dns)
    print('ip destino = ',ip[2]) #ip del servidor wifi que tambien es la ip al que le quiero enviar el socket/archivo
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = ip[2]
    port = 60000
    client.connect((host, port)) ## <-- Failure
    filepath = 'prueba.txt'
    with open(filepath) as fp:
       line = fp.readline()
       while line:
           print("Line {}".format(line.strip()))
           line = fp.readline()
           client.send(line)
    client.close()
```

[image: Fallo que sale en cliente]

Para añadir comentar que los chips son: Lopy de la empresa Pycom y que tanto esta prueba como otras tambén las tengo planteadas en su foro oficial pero aún no me han ayudado a ver si por aquí y en español tengo mas suerte, igualmente dejo el enlace : https://forum.pycom.io/topic/2968/send-a-file-from-one-lopy-to-another-lopy/13

Answer (score 1):

No dispongo de tu hardware, por lo que no  puedo verificar si se trata sólo de lo que voy a explicar, o de si hay más detalles específicos de micro-python y de la plataforma, pero dando por buena la configuración de la Wifi, y centrándome sólo en la comunicación a nivel de sockets, veo los siguientes problemas:

### ChipS

- Estás intentando recibir datos por el socket `s`, que es el socket pasivo por el que admites clientes. Los datos vienen por el socket `conn` que te ha retornado `accept()`.
- El primer bloque de 256 bytes que recibes no lo estás escribiendo en el fichero. Deberías mover el `f.write(data)` al inicio del bucle `while`, pues cuando entras en el bucle `data` ya tiene el resultado del primer `recv()` que haces fuera del bucle (el cual por cierto lo haces bien, sobre `conn`).
- Por si acaso ese primer `recv()` ya devolviera un fin de transmisión, mejor que `while True:` yo pondría  `while data:`.
- No deberías enviar ese "Thank you for connecting" por el socket, ya que el cliente no lo lee.

### ChipC

Desconozco qué te retorna exactamente `ip = w.ifconfig()` pero a juzgar por su posterior uso, supongo que en `ip[2]` tienes una cadena de texto con la IP del servidor.

Quizás no sea así.. verifica el tipo de `ip[2]` por si acaso, ya que dices que te rompe en el `connect()`. Sin embargo, yo no creo que el error se produzca en el `connect()`. En la captura de pantalla que adjuntas, señala una excepción en la línea 41 (y esa no se ve en el listado, pero no es el `connect()`, que sería la 38). Sospecho que se trata del `open()` del fichero, sobre todo porque obtienes un error `ENOENT` (que indica *No such file or directory*, es decir, que el archivo que intentas abrir no existe).

Aparte de eso, desconozco si micropython es Python2 o Python3. Si se trata de Python3, por defecto abre el archivo en modo texto, por lo que leerías cadenas, mientras que lo que debes escribir en el socket son bytes y te fallaría en el `send()`. Mejor el fichero en modo binario.

## Ejemplo

La siguiente versión de ChipS y ChipC funciona en mi máquina, pero con Python normal y omitiendo toda la parte de setup de la wifi, para centrarme sólo en la comunicación por sockets:

#### ChipS

```
import socket                   # Import socket module
import gc


#Iniciamos servidor:
host = ''
port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.
s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
gc.collect()
s.bind((host, port))            # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                     # Now wait for client connection.

print ('Server listening....')

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print ('Got connection from', addr)
    data = conn.recv(256)
    print('Server received', repr(data))

    with open('received_file.txt', 'wb') as f:
        print ('file opened')
        while data:
            print('data=%s', (data))
            print('receiving data...')
            # write data to a file
            f.write(data)
            conn.setblocking(True)
            #print('Memoria->',str(gc.mem_free()))
            data = conn.recv(256)
            #print('M despues->',str(gc.mem_free()))
            if not data:
                break

        f.close()
        print('Successfully get the file')
        print('connection closed')

        # conn.send('Thank you for connecting')
    conn.close()
    gc.collect()
```

#### ChipC

La clase `MockWifi` es para simular lo que haría tu clase `WLAN`, de la que carezco. Es sólo para que cuando llame a `ifconfig()` me de una IP, en este caso la de localhost que es donde tengo al servidor anterior.

```
import socket
import sys

class MockWifi:
    def ifconfig(self):
        return None, None, "127.0.0.1"

def buscarWifi(ssid):
    return True, MockWifi()

ok,w = buscarWifi('Gateway1')
if ok:
    ip = w.ifconfig()
    #(ip, subnet, gateway, dns)
    print('ip destino = ',ip[2]) #ip del servidor wifi que tambien es la ip al   → que le quiero enviar el socket/archivo
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = ip[2]
    port = 60000
    client.connect((host, port)) ## <-- Failure
    filepath = 'prueba.txt'
    with open(filepath) as fp:
       line = fp.readline()
       while line:
           print("Line {}".format(line.strip()))
           client.send(line.encode("utf8"))
           line = fp.readline()
    client.close()
```